# Create Windows Admin user only for UAC prompts but without Desktop access

Tags: windows, administrator, uac

I would like to have an administrator account just for UAC prompts. Is it possible to disable the desktop feature? So that I just can use that account for UAC prompts only and not actually login to see the desktop or something?

I tried changing the `gpedit.msc` option `Deny log on locally`. But after that I couldn't login anymore, even at the UAC prompts.

Is there any other way?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you're asking for is not possible because:

1. Only an administrator can complete a UAC prompt.
2. An administrator user can change any setting in Windows.
3. Therefore, an administrator can  revert a deny logon setting.

As a result, there is no configuration available in Windows that can effectively create the result you're asking for. As shown above, even if you *could* put one in place, the administrator could defeat it.

Additionally, the UAC architecture requires that the user account used to elevate processes not be denied the log on locally user right.

Comment: Despite this, would it meet your purposes to simply *hide* the administrator account from the login screen? If so, I can edit my answer to explain how to do this. @Phil

Comment: Though again, the admin could defeat this setting too.

Comment: A user not being able to log into Windows, but sill authenticate, would not increase security on your system (even if it was possible it would serve no purpose).

Comment: @Ramhound I certainly don't want to improve security with this. It was just asking because I was intereseted.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer accepted if it answered your question.